# How to set environment variables in a WebLogic server

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I am running a web application in a WebLogic (12c) domain. I configured the datasource as a JNDI entry and it works fine. Though, I need to configure other services that require some sort of credentials.
Normally, some environment variables should be enough (or something like secrets in Docker).

But I cannot find a way to **set an environment variable in WebLogic administration console**.

Is this even possible?

Comment: You can set your env vars in the setDomainEnv.sh script under $DOMAIN_HOME/bin

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I was hoping there is a way of accomplishing that using the administration console, similar to JNDI setup

Comment: If you are talking about os env vars it is not possible.